# allow both boolean and integer as input parameter in url

Tags: c#

I need to allow both boolean and integer as input parameter of a particular variable in url. How do i achieve it?

```
   public string PostReggieHeader(string xml, bool metaDataFlag)
    { 
        string xmlData = string.Empty;
        if (true)
        {
            xmlGenerator.ValidateXSD(xml);
            xmlData = UpdatePerformanceValues(documentService.PostReggieHeader(xml, metaDataFlag, Request.RequestUri.AbsoluteUri.ToString()));
        }
        return xmlData;
    }
```

In the above code, I need to allow both bool values as well as integer values as input parameter. Except for '0' ,it is going to treat every other integer as 'true'.

I have already tried the below code but it fails when i take metadataflag=true as it treats it as false. Any suggestions?

```
        [AcceptVerbs("GET", "POST")]
    public string PostReggieHeader(string xml, int? metaDataFlag)
    {
        string xmlData = string.Empty;
        bool metaFlag = metaDataFlag != null ? Convert.ToBoolean(metaDataFlag) : false;
        if (true)
        {
            //xmlGenerator.ValidateXSD(xml))
            xmlData = UpdatePerformanceValues(documentService.PostReggieHeader(xml, metaFlag, Request.RequestUri.AbsoluteUri.ToString()));
        }
        return xmlData;
    }
```

Comment: Side note: `if (true)` is totally *redundant*, just remove it

Comment: Is `if (true)` the correct code?

Comment: It sounds like your posting what you think to be your solution to a question, what are you actually trying to solve?

Comment: Get it as string, then parse it.

Answer (score 3):

Get the input as string then parse it to either bool or int, what ever it is, then based on result decide what you want to do:

```
[AcceptVerbs("GET", "POST")]
public string PostReggieHeader(string xml, string metaDataFlag)
{
    string xmlData = string.Empty;
    bool metaTag = false;
    int metaTagInt = 0;
    bool isBool = false;
    if(metaDataFlag == null || bool.TryParse(metaDataFlag, out metaFlag))
    {
       isBool = true;
    }
    else 
    {
       int.TryParse(metaDataFlag, out metaTagInt);
    }

    //rest of code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

create a model with both string and boolean field and pass that model. Server side fetch the string and boolean properties into respective variable.

It will work for GET as well as post operation.